# discord.py- changing server icon and name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command called `p!potato`, where I want it to change the picture of the server to a file and the name of the server to be "potato". Can someone help?

```py
@client.command()
async def potato(ctx):
    with open('potato.jpg', 'rb') as f:
      icon = f.read()
    await ctx.guild.edit(ctx.guild.icon, icon=icon)
    await ctx.guild.name.edit("potato")
```

Error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to pass `ctx.guild.icon` into `Guild.edit`

```py
await ctx.guild.edit(icon=icon)
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: yeah I know, it says to wait 6 minutes ;-;